# In WinAPI, how do I know when the mouse has moved outside the current window?

Tags: c, winapi, mouseevent

Basically, I want to write a program that shows in a small window the color of the pixel currently pointed by the mouse cursor.

Of course, I could poll the mouse cursor position once in a while, but I would like to opt to a mechanism that calls my code when the mouse cursor has moved, regardless whether it's pointing the current window or not.

Is there some WinAPI trickery that could achieve that functionality?

Comment: Have you checked [the list of mouse input notification messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/mouse-input-notifications) to see if anyone could match your need? (As a hint to how I found it: I searched for `windows mouse messages microsoft docs`, I used `microsoft docs` because I wanted official documentation from Microsofts own documentation site)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=SetWindowsHookEx

Comment: Catch `WM_MOUSELEAVE` in your wndproc. There's no obvious need for hooks here - either the mouse pointer is on top of your window or it isn't - in case of the latter, who cares where it is.

Comment: Perhaps this helps: [Capturing Mouse Movement Outside the Window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/mouse-movement#capturing-mouse-movement-outside-the-window).

Comment: If I get you correctly, you are not interested in leaving your window area but in any movement outside of your own window. My knowledge about Windows stuff is not really fresh but IIRC you need to capture the cursor (`SetCapture`) to be able to get `WM_MOUSEMOVE` outside your window.

Comment: @lun [`WM_MOUSELEAVE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-mouseleave) is *"posted to a window when the cursor leaves the client area"*. It's a one-shot notification. It doesn't help you receive mouse move messages outside the window which is what the question is asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some search, I found this:

```
HHOOK mouseHook = 
    SetWindowsHookExA(
        WH_MOUSE_LL, 
        LowLevelMouseProc,
        hInstance, 
        0);

...

LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelMouseProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    if (wParam == WM_MOUSEMOVE) {
        // Notify me.
    }

    return 0;
}
```